# How can I get data from a MySQL database with Code Igniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my first time trying web programming and I'm currently trying to use Code Igniter. I got this from tutorial but my problem seems a little bit different, I tried several thing but none work

So I want to get data from my db, here's my code

```
public function can_log_in($username, $password){

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 where id_login = '$username' and id_password = '$password'");

    $data = mysql_fetch_row($query); //got error this line, and several line also on libraries and helper
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return  (string) $data[0];
    }else {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Error said:

> Supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

On controller I used:

```
if($this->model_get->can_log_in($username, $password) != "0")
```

Honestly I don't know if this work or should I use `<>` ? haven't got opportunity to tried it, but that's another problem.

So how can I get col1 and col2 here?

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_row($query)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- "expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given"

Comment: You sure you're using `mysqli_` throughout?

Comment: @fred wouldn't it be best suited to follow the current object oriented example? $query->fetch(); for example? As mixing procedural and OO can cause conflicts such as these and complicate the development

Comment: @DarylGill Yes, you're right; my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using codeigniter, just be faithful to it, use its built-in functions:

```
public function can_log_in($username, $password)
{
    $username = $this->db->escape($username); // this automatically adds single quotes
    $password = $this->db->escape($password);
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 where id_login = $username and id_password = $password");
    if($quer->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = $query->row(); // fetches single row
        return $data->col1;
    }
}
```

I also suggest use codeigniters active record, so that you don't have to worry about escaping. They already to it for you:

```
public function can_log_in($username, $password)
{
    $this->db->select('col1', 'col2');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get('table1');

    return ($query->num_rows() > 0);
}
```

In controller:

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
$password = $this->input->post('password');
$can_log = $this->model_name->can_log_in($username, $password);
if($can_log) {
    // yahoo! can log!
} else {
    // sorry but you cannot!
}
```

Comment: yeah the tutorial I saw also said to use "$this->db->select" but my query is much more complicated, I just make it simple here, that's why I tried different way.

Comment: @student080705639 well, you could just use that first answer, if you want more freedom on your queries, just remember to escape those inputs, don't directly inject them

Comment: @student080705639 the second answer was just a suggestion

Comment: Thank, it works. And what if I want to get several column? for example I also want to get col2, can I return it as array and get it in controller?

Comment: @student080705639 i might be suitable to return `return $data;` now, of you want the other columns

Comment: for now I just need one column, might try that later, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 where id_login = '$username' and id_password = '$password'");

$data = $query->row_array();

if ($query->num_rows() == 1){
    return  (string) $data['col1']; // Need to give the field name
}else {
    return "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you need to connect to a database using

`$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myusername","mypassword","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));`

Once you've connected to a database you can query that database using

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tablename");
```

Looking at what you've written, it seems like your code is hitting an error because you haven't connected to a database to query. Once you've established a connection you can submit queries and parse them using a loop to enumerate each row of results of

```
for($i = 0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($data);$i++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($data));
    $username = row[0]; //usernames are column 1
    $password = row[1]; //passwords are column 2
    }
```

And so on. You can read up more on [using PHP at PHP.net](http://php.net/)

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter provides several methods to perform on query results.

See here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

`result()` returns an array of PHP objects.

`row()` returns a single PHP object for that row.

`result_array()` returns an array of arrays.

`row_array()` returns a single array for that row.

`row()` and `row_array()` optionally take a parameter which is the number of the row you'd like to return.

```
$rows = $query->result(); //array of objects
$rows_array = $query->result_array(); //array of arrays
$row = $query->row(); //single object
$row_array = $query->row_array(); //single array
```